# How can we enable multiple checkout in TFS 2010 only for one file in our project?

Tags: tfs, version-control, vcs-checkout

We use TFS 2010 as source control in our project. I disabled multiple checkout on our project and now I need to enable multiple checkout only for App.config file. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to set the multiple checkout attribute on a per file basis.

Answer (score 0):

This should help: 
[Selective multiple checkout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252452.aspx)

I haven't tried it though.